# Serial data logging

Tags: c#, logging, serial-port

I have a device connected to my computer that sends serial data to the computer every 5 mins. I want to write a basic program to capture this serial data every 5 mins and put it into a database. I was hoping to use C# because I have used C# with databases before and found it quite easy.

Can anybody offer me any advice on how I might do this, I really have no idea where to start and I know in theory it sounds easy but when I started it I actually found it really hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using C#, you can use the System.IO.Ports namespace to communicate over the serial ports - there's a nice article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/serialcommunication.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use Python and the [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) module.  I've written an app to communicate over the serial port using pySerial - it's quite easy to use, and can run on many different operating systems including OSX and Windows (I'm assuming you're using Windows).  Python also has built-in support for SQLite.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with capturing data on a serial port is that serial ports aren't thread-safe, so if there is more than one listener, data will be corrupted.

If you are absolutely sure that you're the only one listening for data on this port, .NET has a built-in wrapper, System.IO.Ports.SerialPort, which you can use to connect to COM1, COM2, etc. You'll need to know the rate in bits/sec at which this device sends data (its baud rate), its error-checking (parity) protocol, and the format of the data it is sending (you'll get it as a byte array, which you must convert byte-by-byte into data you can work with). Then, your program should be able to open the port and listen for DataReceived events with a handler that will read and digest the data. Again, it's VERY important that you never have two threads trying to read at once; the easiest way is to set a volatile boolean indicating that a handler is reading data; if another handler is ever spawned while a previous one is still running, the first thing the new one should do is read that value, and since it's set, exit the new handler immediately.

Comment: Using one thread to read isn't rocket science.  Pretty automatic with the DataReceived event.